# Can a JSON object exist without a left-brace

Tags: json

Just a quick question, that I need some clarification on.

Looking at the RFC, a JSON object is

```
object-begin string : value object-end
```

so something like

```
{ "foo" : "bar" }
```

is a valid JSON object. By question is, can an object exist without the begin and end token? Such that

```
"foo" : "bar"
```

or

```
"foo" : {
    "bar" : "baz"
}
```

Looking at some JSON formatters and validators, the former is valid, and the latter is not. If the latter is not valid, is there a technical name for the root object? If `foo.bar` is `baz` in the second example, is there a technical `.foo`?

Comment: Json must start with the left `{`. here's the doc for it http://json.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-3) gives the following grammar for a JSON object:

```
object = begin-object [ member *( value-separator member ) ]
         end-object

member = string name-separator value
```

`begin-object` is a left curly brace (`{`) with optional whitespace on either side, and `end-object` is the right curly brace (`}`), again with optional whitespace.

So, no, neither this:

```
"foo" : "bar"
```

...nor this:

```
"foo" : {
    "bar" : "baz"
}
```

...is a valid JSON object.

In the RFC, the root object (which may also be a string, array, number, `true`, `false`, or `null`) is simply called the "JSON text."

> If `foo.bar` is `baz` in the second example, is there a technical `.foo`?

No, because `foo.bar` isn't JSON, it's JavaScript. The JSON specification (very deliberately) gives no opinion on how any given implementation should represent the data once it's deserialized. To illustrate, here's an example from the RFC:

> This is a JSON object:
>
> ```
> {
>   "Image": {
>       "Width":  800,
>       "Height": 600,
>       "Title":  "View from 15th Floor",
>       "Thumbnail": {
>           "Url":    "http://www.example.com/image/481989943",
>           "Height": 125,
>           "Width":  100
>       },
>       "Animated" : false,
>       "IDs": [116, 943, 234, 38793]
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Its `Image` member is an object whose `Thumbnail` member is an object and whose `IDs` member is an array of numbers.

By way of analogy, your example's `foo` member is an object whose `bar` member is a string—and that's as close as the RFC gets to giving the root object a name.